# Need to use httpd.conf instead of .htaccess for rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache, httpd.conf

I am working on a host that blocks my .htaccess file from being used so I can not change my permalinks using it. I need to figure out what code to use and where to put it in my httpd.conf file to get the same effect.

The code in the .htaccess file is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If your host is blocking .htaccess, you probably don't have access to httpd.conf...otherwise you could just turn on .htaccess files. Get a new host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap that code in a <Directory> directive. Where it goes will depend on what else you've got in your http.conf file. See the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory) for more info.

However, as blockhead says; if your host won't let you use .htaccess files, you've got virtually no chance of being allowed near the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Do I wrap the same code above in the <Directory> ? Not sure how that works.

Comment: Yup. The <Directory> directive just tells Apache that any code within it should only be applied to the directory in question (in this case the dir you were trying to put the .htaccess file into).

Comment: Thanks!! I placed everything in the code above into the httpd.conf file inside the <dirctory> </directory> tags just below the other stuff that was there. After I restarted apache it worked like a champ. 

This is a weird situation where the .htaccess is blocked by a firewall. I have full access to the server but not to the firewall that is doing the damage so I have to do everything through the httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you'd like to block access to GoogleBot throughout your entire server (which may be comprised of hundreds of virtual hosts), you can add this to your httpd.conf file:

```
#setup the root dir
<Directory />
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</Directory>
```

This will send a HTTP 403 Forbidden to anyone who comes in with Googlebot in their user agent string. And this rewrite condition will be applied to ALL virtual hosts, by virtue of applying this to the "/" folder.